# Error: Unexpected Identifier when using next-i18next in config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next

Application keeps throwing an error of " Unexpected Identifier import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next' "

I am pretty new to react/nextjs. My apologies if I am missing something that is completely obvious.

I have essentially been following the docs from [a here](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next). I've tried a couple different configurations on my server.js file, but I don't think this is the correct path to go down..

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const nextI18NextMiddleware = require('next-i18next/middleware').default;

const nextI18next = require('./i18n');

const app = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Server running on port 3000');
    });
});

`

i18n.js config file 

`
import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next';

const NextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
    defaultLanguage: 'en',
    otherLanguages: [ 'de' ],
    localeSubpaths: {
        de: 'de',
        en: 'eng'
    }
});

export default NextI18NextInstance;
`

import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\roger\OneDrive\Desktop\i18next\test\server.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
```

Comment: Looks like you doesn't have babel to transform es modules (`import` syntax) into commonJS (the syntax that node works with).

Comment: You're right. That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Can you comment out @RogyBear the solution you found?